# How can I use ffmpeg on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio, stream, ffmpeg, xcode4

I've been searching a lot for ffmpeg on iphone, and how to use it to steam audio(wma ect.)
but cant figure out how this is done.

can someone please try help me on, how to/what to, download and how i get the ffmpeg lib. into my xcode project, so i can use it to steam some links i have ?

another thing is, i read something about the lisence somewhere. is it really true, that if i use the ffmpeg lib, i need to make my project/code, open source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330082/any-examples-of-how-to-use-ffmpeg-to-play-wma-stream-in-objective-c) existing question on SO, but…

You might want to read the [Media Player Framework Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/_index.html) as the functionality you mention already exists in the iOS SDK for many non WMA files. It is probably going to be less of a headache to convert them to mp3 or another format on your server and go from there using the built-in tech that Apple provides.

Comment: the link for the SO. can i use that solution for my project ? seems like its a mac download, and a alrdy done app for mac ? but, atm. im using the AVPlayer to stream my links.. i have all kinds of formats, mp3, wma ect. ect. so i need a player that can stream all of them, or just one that can stream the wma files i have..